# React sending outdated state when calling a function after event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I have a react + mobx + MaterialUI frontend and I'm facing a problem involving state variables. I have a button that shound trigger a function that converts some state variables into an object and send it other object that will handle the next steps. When I click the button the object is created ok. But when this same function is triggered by the hit enter event the object has empty values (despite when I consoloe.log the value of the state the value logged is correct)
Code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);
  const handleKeyPress = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleSendPing();
    }
  };
  const handleSendPing = () => {
    if (userStore.user) {
      var ping: NewPingDto = {
        recipient: selectedUser,
        locationName: selectedLocation,
        pingMessage: selectedPingMessage,
        senderId: userStore.user.id,
        companyId: userStore.user.companyId,
        dateCreated: new Date(),
        dateLastModified: new Date(),
        isExpired: false,
        isUrgent: urgentPing,
        pingResponse: "",
        isRead: false,
      };
      console.log("foo", ping);
      pingStore.addPing(ping);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("new selectedUser", selectedUser);
  }, [selectedUser]);
```

All buttons have type="button", so it is not caused by an accidental submit (there is no form element in the page too. the useEffect hook show that selectedUser is not ""
Objected printed when I press enter:

```
  {
    "recipient": "",
    "locationName": "",
    "pingMessage": "",
    "senderId": "c0a0d5a0-ffaf-4b7e-8f4a-6b6b8b7b8b71",
    "companyId": 1,
    "dateCreated": "2023-08-21T17:39:25.014Z",
    "dateLastModified": "2023-08-21T17:39:25.014Z",
    "isExpired": false,
    "isUrgent": false,
    "pingResponse": "",
    "isRead": false }
```

Comment: Manually attaching `keydown` events is not good practice. Instead, you can wrap your form elements inside a form, and handle submission with `onSubmit`.

Comment: @Eric While I explained what the issue is and how to address it in my answer, I agree with @technophyle that, if the only reason why you have this is to send the data when Enter is pressed, you might actually want to use a form and its `onSubmit` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a context issue.

The `useEffect` that runs `window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress)` doesn't have any dependencies, so it only runs once, when the component mounts.

At that point, `handleKeyPress` references a function that calls another function, `handleSendPing`. This other `handleSendPing` function's closure, at that point, only sees the initial values for those state variables (`selectedUser`, `selectedUser`, ...), which is probably `undefined` or something similar (e.g. empty string).

One quick fix might be to add `handleKeyPress` as dependency to the `useEffect` that runs `window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress)`, so that the `keydown` event is removed and added again every time `handleKeyPress` is re-created (on every render), keeping the state variables in its closure in-sync with the most recent state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
  };
}, [handleKeyPress]);
```

Alternatively, you can use a `ref` to address this in two different ways:

- Store `handleSendPing` in a ref that `handleSendPing` can then use to call the most up-to-date `handleSendPing` that has the right data in its context.
- Give `handleSendPing` access to the state using a `ref`. This `ref` would store all the store variables `handleSendPing` needs, and is kept in-sync with the state using a `useEffect`:

**Using a `ref` for the callback:**

```
const handleSendPing = () => {
  if (userStore.user) {
    var ping: NewPingDto = {
      recipient: selectedUser,
      locationName: selectedLocation,
      pingMessage: selectedPingMessage,
      senderId: userStore.user.id,
      companyId: userStore.user.companyId,
      dateCreated: new Date(),
      dateLastModified: new Date(),
      isExpired: false,
      isUrgent: urgentPing,
      pingResponse: "",
      isRead: false,
    };

    pingStore.addPing(ping);
  }
};

const handleSendPingRef = useRef(handleSendPing);

useEffect(() => {
  handleSendPingRef.current = handleSendPing;
}, [handleSendPing])

useEffect(() => {
  // No need to re-create this function on each render,
  // so just define it inside the `useEffect` instead:

  const handleKeyPress = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleSendPingRef.current();
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
  };
}, []);
```

**Using a `ref` for the callback's context / dependencies:**

```
const sendPingContextRef = useRef({})

useEffect(() => {
  sendPingContextRef.current = {
    urgentPing,
    selectedUser,
    selectedLocation,
    selectedPingMessage,
    user: userStore.user,
  };
}, [
  urgentPing,
  selectedUser,
  selectedLocation,
  selectedPingMessage,
  userStore.user,
])

const handleSendPing = useCallback(() => {
  const {
    urgentPing,
    selectedUser,
    selectedLocation,
    selectedPingMessage,
    user,
  } = sendPingContextRef.current;

  if (user) {
    var ping: NewPingDto = {
      recipient: selectedUser,
      locationName: selectedLocation,
      pingMessage: selectedPingMessage,
      senderId: user.id,
      companyId: user.companyId,
      dateCreated: new Date(),
      dateLastModified: new Date(),
      isExpired: false,
      isUrgent: urgentPing,
      pingResponse: "",
      isRead: false,
    };

    pingStore.addPing(ping);
  }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  // No need to re-create this function on each render,
  // so just define it inside the `useEffect` instead:

  const handleKeyPress = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleSendPing();
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
  };
}, []);
```

Also, you should take a look at [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and [`exhaustive-deps`](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-exhaustive-deps-linting-warning/) linting rule.